# Keynote keyboard shortcut for moving focus between slide canvas and slides drawer?

Tags: keyboard, keynote

In Keynote '09, is there any way to move the focus between the slides drawer on the left side and the main window with the slide itself, without using the mouse or trackpad?

E.g., when I have made a new slide with shift-cmd-N (then this is automatically selected in the drawer), can I start writing in the slide without having to take my hands off the keyboard to use the mouse?

Answer (score 1):

I was going to ask the same thing for Keynote 6 under 10.10, but I'll chime in here instead..

MacLemon's answer doesn't do anything helpful for me in Keynote on Yosemite.

One can switch between Navigator and Slide Only from the View menu (so shortcuts could be created via System Preferences), but:

- I can't find out how to leave the Navigator visible but change focus
- When the navigator is displayed, it doesn't get focus :(

There's a list of shortcuts [here](https://help.apple.com/keynote/mac/6.5/#/tanfde4a3e6d), but I can't find anything relevant..

Maybe an applescript / automator solution could be concocted.

Answer (score 0):

You can set and check keyboard shortcuts in `SystemPrefrences > Keyboard > [Keyboard & Text Input]` for the entries:

- Move focus to the floating window <kbd>^ F6</kbd>
- Move focus to the window drawer <kbd>⌥ ⌘ '</kbd>

These defaults may vary depending on the keyboard layout and language you're using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Have you verified that these shortcuts work for Keynote, though? For me they work for other apps, but not for keynote...